# Execute a .bat file with argument using QScriptEngine in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a .exe file with a change directory command as follows:-

```
set test="C:\Program Files"
cd /d %test%
```

so i need to execute this .bat file using QScriptEngine.I know this can be achieved through QProcess.But i need to execute using QScriptEngine.I need to set the variable "test" to engine first and then i need to execute the command.On seeing the docs i used the following code:-

```
QScriptEngine engine;
QScriptValue result = engine.evaluate("D:/Moses/test.bat");
qDebug() << result.isError();
```

The out here is true.So some how first i need to set variable test to engine and then evaluate the .bat file.

Comment: The QScriptEngine is **only** for QScript code, aka JavaScript, nothing else. It just can't execute batch-files

Comment: Thanks felix in that case if i want to use JavaScript.From docs we can see evaluate() does not accept any arguments.Say for example i have following Script then how do i use script engine to pass arguments along with my script.

var x = 5;
var y = 6;
var z = x + y;